# Using oauth2 to implement SSO between a desktop application and a web application

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

Is oauth2 designed to handle single-sign-on between a desktop application and a webapp?

The scenario looks like this:

- The desktop app has a username/password login
- After a user is authenticated in the desktop app, there are links to a browser app which when opened, should automatically authenticate the user which is logged in in the desktop app

Would oauth2 / oidc be the right choice for this? If yes, how would the single-sign-on look like?

Comment: [Device Authorization Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/device-authorization-flow)

Comment: @defalt i think the device authorization flow is the other way round: the device needs to authenticate against an authorization server. What i'm looking for is: We have a trusted device, where a user is already authenticated (not via the authorization server). then that device opens a link in a webpage, and now the authenticated user on the device should automatically be authenticated in the web app.

Comment: OIDC doesn't support this.